# Select date in P1 and copy to the the rest of the cells in P Column

Tags: excel, vba

Pretty much what I listed in the subject line with the exception this needs to only add data to column P if there is data in adjacent rows.

For example if there are 20 rows of data I only need this to copy P1 through P20. But the rows will fluctuate, sometimes there may be 50 rows, sometimes there may be 5 etc....

```
Sub DaysToPay()
    'DaysToPay Macro 
    Range("P2").Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]+10" 
    Range("P3").Select
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to get from say, P1 until the last data entry in that column? `Dim rng as Range // Set rng = Range(Cells(1,"P"),Cells(rows.Count,"P").End(xlUp))`

Comment: It's a good idea to show some work when you ask a question. Try something, then ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Free()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long 'last row

lr = ws.Range("P" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("P1:P" & lr).Copy                      '<-- Copy
ws.Range("?").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues        '<-- Paste where?

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I guess it would have helped to show what I already had. As you can see this takes the data from a row and add/subtracts from it than pastes it into P1, If there was a way to do this but have it extend down for all the rows that have data this would be amazingly helpful.@urdearboy


Sub DaysToPay()
'
' DaysToPay Macro
' DaysToPay
'

'
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]+10"
    Range("P3").Select
End Sub